# How does one come up with the anti-derivative?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I understand how to answer the questions when involving the anti-derivative and integrals, however logically I don't understand what exactly an anti-derivative is and how it affects a function.

Comment: In short: Let $F$ be the anti-derivative of $f$ then $F'=f$.

Comment: An anti-derivative of a function $f$ is another function, say $g$, such that $g'=f$

Comment: You've asked a small series of closely-related questions. Have you read the relevant sections of your textbook carefully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An antiderivative of a function $f$, by definition, is a function $F$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$. That's all.

Finding an antiderivative of a function is no easy task, however. In fact, there are famous examples of functions, like $e^{x^2}$, which have derivatives that *cannot* be written "in closed form", meaning they cannot be expressed as products, sums and compositions of elementary functions like $\exp, x^n, \sin,...$.